# java recursion create list of lists with all possible combinations

Tags: java, arraylist

Here is the problem: I have a number of lists. To start, I simply choose lists of String, let us take 2 simple ones: `[A,B,C]` and `[W,X,Y,Z]`
I need to fill in my `permutationResult` that is an ArrayList of ArrayList such that:

```
permutationResult  = [[A, W], [A, X], [A, Y], [A, Z], [B, W], [B, X], [B, Y], [B, Z], [C, W], [C, X], [C, Y], [C, Z]]
```

I manage to get the combinations by recursion, but when I try to store the results in my `permutationResult` List, this list seems to be completely erased and replaced by the last permutation at each time. I copy my code below and the result of code running. I added some `System.out.println` in order to notice where it goes wrong, but I can't figure out what to do so any help is welcome.
Thank you in advance. (The execution of this code is also below)

```
public void permute(ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> all_Lists, ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> permutationResult, ArrayList<String> objectPutInList, int indexOfList) {
        if ((indexOfList == all_Lists.size()) && (objectPutInList.size() == all_Lists.size())) {
            permutationResult.add(objectPutInList);
            System.out.println("-----------> : "+objectPutInList);
            System.out.println("put in index : "+permutationResult.lastIndexOf(objectPutInList));
            System.out.println("combinations are : "+permutationResult);
            objectPutInList.remove(objectPutInList.size() - 1);
            System.out.println("2 combinations are : "+permutationResult);
            System.out.println("");
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < all_Lists.get(indexOfList).size(); ++i) 
        {
            objectPutInList.add(all_Lists.get(indexOfList).get(i));
            permute(all_Lists, permutationResult, objectPutInList, indexOfList + 1);
        }
        if (objectPutInList.size() != 0){
            objectPutInList.remove(objectPutInList.size() - 1);
        }
        return;
    }
```

**Here is the execution:**

```
-----------> : [A, W]
put in index : 0
combinations are : [[A, W]]
2 combinations are : [[A]]

-----------> : [A, X]
put in index : 1
combinations are : [[A, X], [A, X]]
2 combinations are : [[A], [A]]

-----------> : [A, Y]
put in index : 2
combinations are : [[A, Y], [A, Y], [A, Y]]
2 combinations are : [[A], [A], [A]]

-----------> : [A, Z]
put in index : 3
combinations are : [[A, Z], [A, Z], [A, Z], [A, Z]]
2 combinations are : [[A], [A], [A], [A]]

-----------> : [B, W]
put in index : 4
combinations are : [[B, W], [B, W], [B, W], [B, W], [B, W]]
2 combinations are : [[B], [B], [B], [B], [B]]

-----------> : [B, X]
put in index : 5
combinations are : [[B, X], [B, X], [B, X], [B, X], [B, X], [B, X]]
2 combinations are : [[B], [B], [B], [B], [B], [B]]

-----------> : [B, Y]
put in index : 6
combinations are : [[B, Y], [B, Y], [B, Y], [B, Y], [B, Y], [B, Y], [B, Y]]
2 combinations are : [[B], [B], [B], [B], [B], [B], [B]]

-----------> : [B, Z]
put in index : 7
combinations are : [[B, Z], [B, Z], [B, Z], [B, Z], [B, Z], [B, Z], [B, Z], [B, Z]]
2 combinations are : [[B], [B], [B], [B], [B], [B], [B], [B]]

-----------> : [C, W]
put in index : 8
combinations are : [[C, W], [C, W], [C, W], [C, W], [C, W], [C, W], [C, W], [C, W], [C, W]]
2 combinations are : [[C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C]]

-----------> : [C, X]
put in index : 9
combinations are : [[C, X], [C, X], [C, X], [C, X], [C, X], [C, X], [C, X], [C, X], [C, X], [C, X]]
2 combinations are : [[C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C]]

-----------> : [C, Y]
put in index : 10
combinations are : [[C, Y], [C, Y], [C, Y], [C, Y], [C, Y], [C, Y], [C, Y], [C, Y], [C, Y], [C, Y], [C, Y]]
2 combinations are : [[C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C]]

-----------> : [C, Z]
put in index : 11
combinations are : [[C, Z], [C, Z], [C, Z], [C, Z], [C, Z], [C, Z], [C, Z], [C, Z], [C, Z], [C, Z], [C, Z], [C, Z]]
2 combinations are : [[C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C], [C]]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the following recursive solution?
You can make use of `Set` in order to remove duplicates.
The idea here mimics two for loops. You iterate over first list

```
go(a.subList(1, a.size()), b, acc);
```

and then through the second

```
go(a, b.subList(1, b.size()), acc);
```

Please keep in mind that Java is rarely considered as first-choice language for recursive problems.

```
public class Perm {

    public List<List<String>> perm(List<String> a, List<String> b) {
        Set<List<String>> acc = new HashSet<>();
        go(a, b, acc);
        return new LinkedList<>(acc);
    }

    private void go(List<String> a, List<String> b, Set<List<String>> acc) {
        if (a.size() == 0 || b.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        List<String> aa = new LinkedList<>();
        aa.add(a.get(0));
        aa.add(b.get(0));
        acc.add(aa);

        go(a.subList(1, a.size()), b, acc);
        go(a, b.subList(1, b.size()), acc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> a = new LinkedList<>();
        a.add("X");
        a.add("Y");
        a.add("Z");

        List<String> b = new LinkedList<>();
        b.add("A");
        b.add("B");
        b.add("C");
        b.add("D");
        System.out.println(new Perm().perm(a, b));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! However this method take only 2 lists and the purpose of my question is to handle a dynamic number of lists. Any insight?

Answer (score 1):

Well, I guess I figured it out!
Here is the answer to my question in case we have one or several lists:
Thank you slawekpl for your prompt reply yesterday.
PS: This is the first time I post a question on this platform, so I apologize if I don't know how to display properly my codes :)

```
public class TestObject {

    static ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> permute(Object val, ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> all_Lists) {

        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> permuteOneList;
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> permuteSeveralLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

        if (all_Lists.size() != 1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < all_Lists.get(0).size(); i++) {
                permuteOneList = permute(all_Lists.get(0).get(i), new ArrayList(all_Lists.subList(1, all_Lists.size())));
                if (!val.equals("")) {
                    ArrayList<Object> comb;
                    for (int j = 0; j < permuteOneList.size(); j++) {
                        comb = permuteOneList.get(j);
                        comb.add(0, val);
                        permuteSeveralLists.add(comb);
                    }
                } else {
                    permuteSeveralLists.addAll(permuteOneList);
                }
            }
            return permuteSeveralLists;
        } 
        else {
            permuteOneList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < all_Lists.get(0).size(); i++) {
                ArrayList<Object> comb = new ArrayList<Object>();
                if (val ==""){
                    comb.add(all_Lists.get(0).get(i));
                    permuteOneList.add(comb);
                }
                else {
                    comb.add(val);
                    comb.add(all_Lists.get(0).get(i));
                    permuteOneList.add(comb);
                }
            }
            return permuteOneList;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Object> l1 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        l1.add("a");
        l1.add("b");
        l1.add("c");
        l1.add("d");
        ArrayList<Object> l2 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        l2.add("w");
        l2.add("x");
        l2.add("y");
        l2.add("z");
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> all_Lists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();

        ArrayList<Object> l3 = new ArrayList<Object>();
        l3.add("1");
        l3.add("2");
        l3.add("3");
        all_Lists.add(l1);
        all_Lists.add(l2);
        all_Lists.add(l3);
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> permt = permute("", all_Lists);
        System.out.println("size : " + permt.size());
        System.out.println("permutation is : " + permt);
    }

}
```